# Where should I place my Sitecore Custom Module file assets?

Tags: module, best-practices

When developing sitecore modules, is it recommended to install the different custom files in the **sitecore folder** or **sitecore modules folder**? Please see below screenshot:

[image]

Actually, I am installing most of my files (aspx, xml, css, js) in the sitecore modules folder.

I know that the Sitecore folder is mainly specific to the Sitecore CMS but can I add my custom files in this folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is not a good practice to install in Sitecore folder your custom code. In Sitecore Modules are installed modules like WFFM, EXM , etc.

Also if you override some custom functionality is recommended to add into a **\sitecore\shell\Override** folder.

You need to have a separation between your code and Sitecore code. 
  Normally css, js you add into an Assets folder in root folder. 
  Views you need add into Areas folder if you use MVC Areas or into Views folder if you not use Areas.

Layouts, sublayouts you add into Layouts folder but is recommended to have subfolders for different type of sublayouts.

Comment: What if I am developing a sitecore custom tool? The reason why I want to place my files in the Sitecore folder is because I am having problems to load the upload form as i am getting document not found.

Comment: You add into Override folder.

Comment: So if I understand well, any custom modules being implemented, let say I am implementing a tool to generate URLs, I should place it in the Override folder, correct?

Comment: It depends what kind of modules you have. I will say this kind of module if you want to use it like a standalone module add it to Sitecore Modules. In override folder you add Xaml that you override from Sitecore.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the guidelines doesn't mention where in the filesystem you're meant to live. I'd say going with `/sitecore modules` is probably fine. Make sure you find a suitable location there, and make sure *all* of your files live in your selected folder. Don't spread out into multiple root folders and such.

I also highly recommend you read through the official [Sitecore Module implementation practices](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/831724) guide, which gives you a load of guidance on how to manage templates, renderings and other Sitecore assets for your module.